# What kind of coil do I need for wireless power transmission?

Tags: transformer, inductor, wireless-charging, outlet

**My project:** I am trying to design a system for a school project that will help with electrical safety. My idea is a wireless electrical socket/outlet. It will use a transformer to convert 120v to 6v, and the 6v is sent through a coil, producing an electromagnetic field that transfers power to an identical coil on the other side.

**My Question:** What kind of coil would I need? The inductance? The wiring gauge? And finally, would I actually have to get the coil to be rated at 300 amps?

**Diagram:**

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foSG75.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Where did the 300A figure come from?

Comment: Probably from the assumption that if the source outlet provides 15A at 120V, the out put should provide 300A at 6V..

Comment: What equipment are you wanting to supply power to?

Comment: not defined are the requirements for safety. e.g. double insulation to 3kV and output voltage at 300A or total power out plus any switches.  Air coupling (wireless) will not possible with 300A at 50/60Hz   Also project function is not defined.

Comment: I'm guessing here that you'd need a couple of facing silicon steel cores about a meter square and weighing several tons to get decent coupling with a 300mm separation at 50/60Hz.

Comment: Refer to the Qi wireless charging standard.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qi_%28standard%29
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resonant_inductive_coupling

Comment: Remember that the magnetic field strength is proportional to the cube of the distance. That means that if you are getting 1 unit of energy at 1 unit of distance, when you increase the distance to 2 units you'll get 1/3 the power transfer and at 3 units you'll get 1/9th. This is why wireless power transfer at a distance will never be viable beyond short distances *or* devices with small powers

Comment: is that 300A or 300mA?  your question is "out to lunch"

Comment: I like to add a power supply that can deliver 300A is dangerous in its very own way. Check with a car battery. You don't want something like this in a school project.

Comment: poorly defined project  -1

Answer (score -1):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCXvFv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

So do you know how to choose the correct wire gauge for primary and secondary for 120 turns around high permeability laminated steel to get 529 mH or 4.4 mH per turn?

Comment: This is basic schematic of a high power soldering gun, perhaps not what you had in mind.

Comment: But it what was defined, rather poorly